# Arrange images on a single A4 page for printing?

Tags: photos, printing, image-editing

I have a number of images I would like to size to something like 3.5"x2.5" and arrange with gaps on A4 or A5 sized paper.

Is there some program or utility that can arrange photos for printing like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question provides very little detail. For example, we have no idea whether you're talking about an iPhone, iPad, Mac, etc? And which version of iOS or macOS you're running?

However, assuming you're talking about a Mac, you can do exactly what you want with the Photos app (included with Mac OS X 10.10.3 and above) or the earlier iPhoto app included with Mac OS X since January 2002.

To do what you want:

1. Launch Photos
2. Select the photos you'd like to print on your page (e.g. select four photos)
3. Go to File > Print (or just do the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> keyboard shortcut)
4. In the Print page that appears you'll be able to select A4, A5, and other paper sizes
5. You can also choose the size of the photos (including custom sizes, contact sheet, standard photo sizes, etc)
6. The Columns slider allows you to set how many columns of photos are to be printed on the page
7. The Margins slider lets you determine how much of a gap you want between your photos
8. You can also set and format captions, choose colour options, and select paper type

I'm sure if you have a play with these settings you'll be able to achieve what you want.

If you were after something else (e.g. a solution for iPad) or wanted a third party app instead, please improve your original question.

Comment: Why would I care if this app runs on iOS or mac? I'm trying to find a solution, not a tool. And it sounds like you understood exactly what I was trying to do, making your comment unnecessary. I tried photos originally, but maybe I missed the advanced options.

And everyone is running latest OSX and iOS, for most values of everyone. If I was running this on a powerpc I'd specify.

Comment: Being ungracious after the fact really will not improve your chances of getting help. We cannot see over your shoulder, we don't know what you already tried & dismissed. Doing your own research first & telling us why the results were unsatisfactory would go a long way. Your question as it stands is far too broad & reads like a shopping recommendation.

Comment: Can we all agree that the feedback is not personal, but trying to get at the core of the problem so that people _know_ precisely what answer is needed instead of guessing? @StefanKendall and @ tetsujin

Comment: @bmike there was never any confusion here and the question was answered. The confusion was a false argument that no one experienced as proven by the exact answer I needed. Hopefully anyone searching for "arrange images a4 osx" can now find this answer.

Comment: @StefanKendall I'm glad I was able to answer your question, but just a tip for future reference. Many users posting questions here aren't running the latest version of iOS or MacOS. Also, many only have one Apple device (e.g. We get many questions from iPhone users who use a Windows computer not a Mac, etc). In answering your question I read between the lines and got it right, but I've also got it wrong many times. Providing more details just helps make it easier for the community to answer the question without guesswork. Anyway, time to move on.